# JDBC hung query client recovery

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, timeout

I am running the combination of Microsoft JDBC driver and DBCP and see one query hanging in:

```
    ...
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1654) ~[sqljdbc4-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:3694) ~[sqljdbc4-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:5022) ~[sqljdbc4-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:388) ~[sqljdbc4-3.0.jar:na]
    ...
```

configuring driver with non zero query timeout does not help (it seems that when it hangs while reading from the socket then it is another type of timeout).

I don't want to change the socket read timeout for the application.

For now I have changed to C3P0 pool that has timeout-based forced connections collector, I don't like it too much, but I'll have to use it unless I find a better option.

So, questions
Does anyone know this problem and underlying details?
What do you think is the best way to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: can you post the query that hangs. BoneCP is better solution in my opinion

Comment: @sheldonCooper - query is a stored proc call, a bug in some nested code on the DB side is the reason of the hangup, I don't have the SQL at hands. Why is BoneCP better?

Comment: With BoneCP you can have partitions which I think is not possible with others and http://jolbox.com/index.html?page=http://jolbox.com/benchmarks.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the java.sql.Statement directly, try setting the timeout.

```
statement.setQueryTimeout(int seconds);
```

Comment: is it different from passing "queryTimeout=xxx;" to the driver? I tried that the first thing and it didn't help

Comment: I guess that's the same thing